# Finding whether a string is an alphabetically ordered word in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

The prompt is to write a method, ordered_word?, which returns whether the letters in a word occur in alphabetical order. Assume the string contains only lowercase letters with no spaces or punctuation. My solution is the following:

```
def ordered_word?(word)
  letters=word.split("")
  (0..(letters.length-1)).all? do |i|
    if letters[i]<=letters[i+1]
      return true
    end
  end 
end
```

However, it doesn't pass all my test cases and I don't understand why. The argument "amz" and "zma" produce expected output, but if it's something like "abcdgfe", it's still returning true even though that is not an ordered word.

Comment: Aside: what is the max value of `i`? What does this mean about `letters[i+1]`? Trivially, input of "abc" will fail.

Comment: `arr = word.chars; arr == arr.sort `

Comment: @SagarPandya : This would just yield an array of the letters in *word*, in sorted order.

Comment: @user1934428 It does not 'just yield [a sorted array]', consider this slight variation for clarity: `arr = word.chars; already_sorted = (arr == arr.sort)`. That is, the code is *not* assigning the result of arr.sort..

Comment: Arrrgh! I missed the double-equal sign. You're right.

Answer (score 3):

The `return` is returning from the entire method. You need to just "return" from the block, by not specifying `return` and just relying on the last line of the block being the returned value, so like:

```
def ordered_word?(word)
  letters=word.split("")
  (0..(letters.length-1)).all? do |i|
    letters[i]<=letters[i+1]
  end
end
```

Though you could use some of the convenient methods of ruby to shorten this to:

```
def ordered_word?(word)
  word.each_char.each_cons(2).all? do |first, second|
    first <= second
  end
end
```

Comment: The second solution proposed here is the best as it does not create any unnecessary intermediary objects although a `downcase` would eb recommended unless `'abC'` is not considered "ordered" . However the first solution could be shortened as well and avoid the `Array` such that `(0...word.length).all? { |i|
    word[i]<=word[i+1]
}` but same issue as above

Comment: Yeah, first solution is only there because it's OP's code with minimal changes to get it working. `downcase` would also be a good idea, but the prompt stated to assume only lowercase characters, so un-necessary in this example

Answer (score 3):

A very simple comparison would be this:

```
word.chars.sort.join == word
```

What this does is takes the characters of the string as an array, sorts them alphanumerically, and then joins them back together into a string. This string is then compared to the original string, and if it is equal, then no reordering was done and the string was already ordered.

If you wanted to extend this as a method to the `String` class:

```
class String

  def ordered?
    chars.sort.join == self
  end
end
```

Comment: Good idea! I think you need `.split(//)` in the first example. Or `.char` as the second.

Comment: @iGian Good call, cut-paste error from my "first-draft", lol. Fixed the first example to match the second example that I intended.